# Corporate Finance Book Recommendations

Tags: corporate-finance

Can you share your recommendations for corporate finance if you have any?

A slightly more detailed version would be better:

For example, something like:

Advanced Undergrad: Varian's $\textit{Intermediate Microeconomics}$
Ph.D. 1st-year: MWG's $\textit{Microeconomic Theory}$

An example for corporate finance would be lke:

MBA-level:  ~
Corporate Finance Theory-specific:  ~
Ph.D. level: ~

Thanks!

Comment: The Theory of Corporate Finance by Jean Tirole suitable for grad students and advanced undergrads.

Comment: @Bayesian Thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

frequent Corporate Finance textbooks are

MBA level -

> Berk and de Marzo (2017) - *Corporate Finance*, 4th ed. (Stanford)

Advanced undergrad and corp theory-specific -

> Grinblatt and Titman - *Financial Markets & Corporate Strategy*

PhD 1st year level - 
strictly articles from *Journal of Finance*, *Review of Financial studies*, etc, that empirically look at mergers and acquisitions, corporate governance, debt-shareholder agency problems, etc. Seminars on the subject typically have participants play discussants of existing recent work.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

I like some bits of Van der Wijst ["Finance: A Quantitative Introduction"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/finance/F9FC707C89E8D17D950235708400E26F) (2013, Cambridge University Press). I have not read the whole book, but I found some examples in it to be very clear and helpful.

From a description in Amazon:

> By providing a solid theoretical basis, this book introduces modern finance to readers, including students in science and technology, who already have a good foundation in quantitative skills. It combines the classical, decision-oriented approach and the traditional organization of corporate finance books with a quantitative approach that is particularly well suited to students with backgrounds in engineering and the natural sciences. This combination makes finance much more transparent and accessible than the definition-theorem-proof pattern that is common in mathematics and financial economics. The book's main emphasis is on investments in real assets and the real options attached to them, but it also includes extensive discussion of topics such as portfolio theory, market efficiency, capital structure and derivatives pricing.